# How to create trigger to auto-fill a column in my application as counter?

Tags: sql-server

I have written a trigger, but it doesn't work well.

[image]

How to make it work to fill the column automatically, without user intervention, when I create an activity?

I use SQL Server.

Comment: Post the code as text, not as a picture please.

Comment: Well, you've defined an **INSTEAD OF INSERT** trigger - but you're not actually **inserting** the values that you get..... so of course it doesn't work...... **EITHER** make this an **AFTER INSERT** trigger, or then you have to **do the INSERT** yourself (in an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger)

Comment: didn't work as my needs :(

Answer (score 0):

You need an after trigger and not an instead of trigger change your trigger to after trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerName
AFTER INSERT
  ON TableName 
BEGIN
  //Your Code
END;
```

Comment: I tried to put (AFTER) but it didn't work . I want to fill the field automatically !!

Comment: the issue with your code is you are trying to update a table before the insert is happening can you show the code you tried with after?